# Stop processing request when request times out

Tags: node.js, timeout, request

From what I can tell, due to the nature of the event loop in Node.js there is no way to easily stop a request from being processed after it has already been handed off to the callback function.

Since each event callback is not tied to any other specific process flow or event, once a callback is added to the event loop's queue or is currently being processed, it will continue to be processed even if the request.on('timeout') handler is triggered.

Is there any way to stop processing a request if it times out? The only way I can think of to partially solve this problem is to add a check at the top of each async callback that is executed during a request to see if the request has timed out and, if it has, then just return immediately and stop the successive callbacks.

However, this doesn't solve the issue if there is already an outstanding asynchronous call being processed that was made from the timed-out request. In that case, unless you destroy the connection to whatever is doing the async processing (e.g. executing a MySQL query) it will continue and eventually call the async callback associated with it.

This is not an issue in other programming paradigms like PHP + Apache since apache creates a new PHP process for each incoming request, so if the request times out the process is eventually killed and the entire execution flow is stopped.

Has anyone run into this issue and found an existing library or custom way to easily solve this?

EDIT: To add a specific example:

Right now we have an API built in node that processes incoming requests to track analytics, publishes the request data to a rabbit queue, then returns a response. If the request comes in and for some reason the request takes longer than 30 seconds to process, it will time out and an error response will be sent to the client. At this point the client will try to make the same call again (so we don't lose analytics).

However, since there's no connection between the request itself and the call to publish to rabbit (except the fact that it was that request that initiated the publish) there's no way to stop the publishing of that data. Therefore, if the rabbit server eventually finishes processing the publish request there will now be duplicate data, since the client has now made 2 (or more) requests.

The only way to stop the initial request from completing the publish is to destroy the rabbit connection when the request times out. That way the initial publish is stopped and the retry request from the client will not duplicate it. However, this same type of manual destroying of a connection would need to be done for any async call that is made throughout the request. If I have 5 outstanding async calls when the timeout happens I'll need to destroy all 5 async connections (whether they be connections to rabbit, mysql, mongo, etc.).

The problem, however, goes beyond connections that have already been established when the request times out. Even if the request times out before the publish to rabbit was initiated, the function that was called to handle that request has already been executed and will not stop unless there is some check at various locations to check if the request has timed out and to return immediately.

Comment: You can store the rabbit connection on a global object with an id (could be client ip or a cookie value or whatever) and you can retrieve this connection on the next request. ALSO you can store the rabbit connection on the socket itself and listen for 'close', and kill the rabbit connection when that happens. Killing means calling 'close' or setting a flag so in your own code it bails. Going for the first option, you can have multiple socket/http connections converge to a single server 'connection' by some id.

Comment: @DDS Right now I attach the rabbit connection to the request, then on timeout I close the connection. However, I'm hoping for a more general solution that encompasses the ability to stop processing the entire request flow. Right now I can't think of a good way unless I introduce things into node that are completely contrary to node (create a new process for each incoming request) or are redundant/verbose (add a check before each async call to see if the request has timed out). Either of these methods don't seem very intuitive.

Comment: If you use node 0.11.x, you can use generator-based functions ([gen-run](https://github.com/creationix/gen-run), [suspend](https://github.com/jmar777/suspend)), and you can modify it to toss exceptions into the generator function whenever you want to abort the function, in combination with ignoring the original next callback. You then have the power for a real 'abort' call on a 'running function' (which is actually suspended of course). This in essence would put a check after each callback invocation and push a 'bail out' all the way to the function exit (unless you catch and ignore errors).

Comment: If you do *not* use node 0.11.x, you can still use generators (ES6), but you have to compile it to vanilla JS (ES5), which you can do with [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler).

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably get better answers with a more specific question. And technical details like "a mysql query" are easier to discuss than vague non-technical terms like "a request".

> The only way I can think of to partially solve this problem is to add a check at the top of each async callback that is executed during a request to see if the request has timed out and, if it has, then just return immediately and stop the successive callbacks

You don't now, nor will you ever need code like that in node.js. No one does anything like that because it's not a problem. Even if it was, it makes sense to solve lower in the stack than in a application program.

> This is not an issue in other programming paradigms like PHP + Apache since apache creates a new PHP process for each incoming request, so if the request times out the process is eventually killed and the entire execution flow is stopped.

This is even LESS of an issue in node.js because for an incoming HTTP request, there's not even a new process or even a new thread. What ends of happening is essentially:

- Client connects and sends a GET request
- OS receives the connection
- node receives the GET request
- Let's say at this point the client process (browser) is suddenly killed on the client machine
- Exactly how this plays out has a few scenarios. If the power goes out in the house where the browser is, nothing comes over the wire, in other scenarios, the client my send packets to close the TCP connection early.
- But **it doesn't really matter** on the node side. You process the request, make your DB queries, render your HTML, and worst case is once that work is done, nobody cares, but it's just a single GET request. Your application should be doing many many of these per second. Thinking of completing that processing of that request as "a problem" is just wrong. It's not a problem, nor is there anything I've ever heard of that can realistically be done about it in any programming language. The server literally cannot distinguish a client that is just correctly waiting for the response from a client that lost power 200ms ago. HTTP does not have a "CANCEL" method. In fact, it is probably more semantically correct to complete the entire HTTP request. For example, if a web browser sends you a complete HTTP POST for a credit card purchase, but disconnects before you respond, that transaction should go through to completion. To abort it after starting would be incorrect.

Comment: I don't agree. Not all http requests are served in subsecond times. Some may take hours (downloads) and take significant resources (read large file). Also, these are quite likely to be dropped by clients (tired of waiting). Considering this, it may be advantageous to have an early-out. AFAICT, Sarah is right when she says you need to do this manually. That said, it's not necessary to this at every callback. It's sufficient to break a loop if there is one. If there are no loops or pipes, then it would _likely_ not be worth it to provide an early-out mechanism (as your answer states).

Comment: Ah, yes, clear, specific examples get you clear answers. Downloads are a low-percentage thing for unspecified node/php apps. General questions based on FUD get broad answers.

Comment: I'm looking for a broad answer since this is a broad, and far-reaching, problem. The issue arises whenever you have an explicit or implicit timeout or dropped request. If the request is closed for any reason (due to a timeout or the request being closed by the client or somewhere down the line), there's no way to easily stop the processing of that request. See my edit for more clarification.

Comment: @Sarah Did you ever figure this out? I have similar questions.